# css can't working in frontend magento 2

Tags: css, frontend-error

I have deleted `/pub/static/` and `/var` folder except **.htaccess** and run **cmd**

```
setup:upgrade 
setup:static-content:deploy 
indexer:reindex 
cache:clean 
cache:flush
```

But still some content is not showing,like shopping cart, menu left.

[image: css not load]

Comment: Check In inspect element whether it is getting css from your `.css` file or any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```